# I've created trigrams, how do I save this as a parquet file? How can I getItems from column _1 when it's not recognised as a column? (PySpark)

Tags: python, pyspark, nlp, n-gram, trigram

***Part one***

Here's my code:

```
trigrams = ngrams(cleaned_text, 3)
trigramsCounts = Counter(trigrams)
trigramDf = trigramsCounts.most_common(100)
```

Sample of the output when displayed (using made up data for this example):

| _1 | _2 |
| --- | --- |
| “_1":"how","_2":"are","_3":"you" | 102 |
| “_1":"good","_2":"thank","_3":"you" | 96 |
| “_1":"are","_2":"you","_3":"okay" | 72 |

(column _1 text is actually in braces {} as well, not sure if that's relevant, but stackoverflow won't let me post with them)

I have been trying to getItems so I can put each word into a separate column, and then concat this to create a string of the 3 words. This is the code:

```
finalDf = trigramDf.withColumn('Word_1', col('_1').getItem(0))
finalDf = finalDf.withColumn('Word_2', col('_1').getItem(1))
finalDf = finalDf.withColumn('Word_3', col('_1').getItem(2))
```

But I get this error (which I assume is because the trigramDf variable isn't actually being recognised as a data frame).

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> /tmp/ipykernel_25874/2346936649.py in 
> ----> 1 finalDf = finalDf.withColumn('Word', col('_1').getItem(0))
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'withColumn'

---

***Part two***

I also want to save the output as a parquet file so I can use these to form data visualisations (e.g. a word cloud), but again I keep getting an error.

This is the code (example):

```
finalDf.write.parquet('abfss://datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/desired_folder_location',mode = 'overwrite')
```

This is the error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_25874/3576806399.py in 
> ----> 1 finalDf.write.parquet('abfss://datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/desired_folder_location',
> mode = 'overwrite')
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'

---

1. How do I get the trigramDf to be recognised as a df?
2. Why won't it let me save it as a parquet file?

I appreciate this is a lengthy query but any help will be appreciated - thank you.

Comment: what is type of clean_text and trigramDF, and which ngram function you are using..

Comment: @qaiser the cleaned text has been generated from a column that has many rows of free text comments, which has then been passed through an rdd.toLocalIterator() to create one string of text, grouping those comments altogether. That unique string has had all digits, punctuation and stop words removed, switched all to lower case, word tokenized and lemmatized.

The ngram function I've used is "ngrams" from nltk.util, which I use to pass through a 3 to get the trigram (trigrams = ngrams(cleaned_text, 3)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved! Here's how:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType

emptyString = []
schema = StructType([
    StructField('_1', StringType(), True),
    StructField('_2', IntegerType(), True)])

for w in trigramDf:
    emptyString.append((' '.join(w[0]), w[1]))

BOWdf = spark.createDataFrame(emptyString,schema)
```

As this is now a data frame, saving the output is now no issue either.